# Feathers-mongoose : Get by custom attribute in feathers-mongoose

Tags: javascript, feathersjs

I have a very basic feathers service which stores data in mongoose using the feathers-mongoose package. The issue is with the get functionality. My model is as follows:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
  const mongooseClient = app.get('mongooseClient');
  const { Schema } = mongooseClient;
  const messages = new Schema({
    message: { type: String, required: true }
  }, {
    timestamps: true
  });

  return mongooseClient.model('messages', messages);
};
```

When the a user runs a GET command :

```
curl http://localhost:3030/messages/test
```

I have the following requirements

1. This essentially tries to convert test to ObjectID.  What i would 
   like it to do is to run a query against the message attribute 
   {message : "test"} , i am not sure how i can achieve this. There is 
   not enough documentation for to understand to write or change this
   in the hooks. Can some one please help
2. I want to return a custom error code (http) when a row is not found or does not match some of my criterias. How can i achive this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Feathers [before hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html) you can set [context.result](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html#contextresult) in which case the original database call will be skipped. So the flow is

- In a before `get` hook, try to find the message by name
- If it exists set `context.result` to what was found
- Otherwise do nothing which will return the original `get` by id

This is how it looks:

```
async context => {
  const messages = context.service.find({
    ...context.params,
    query: {
      $limit: 1,
      name: context.id
    }
  });

  if (messages.total > 0) {
    context.result = messages.data[0];
  }

  return context;
}
```

How to create custom errors and set the error code is documented in the [Errors API](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/errors.html).

Comment: Worked like charm! Really loving this framework. I have a slightly off topic question. What exactly does ...context.params do ?  When invoking Service A , from B, is there a subset of the context which needs to be passed to it? Cheers!

Comment: It's the [JavaScript spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax). It is usually a good idea to pass params along because it could contain important information like the current user or if it was an external call.